# Program never prints any output

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

void userInput(int& Length, char& AuthorLevel);

int main(void)
{
int Length;         // The length of the story.
int counter = 0;
int numA = 0;
int numB = 0;
int numC = 0;
char AuthorLevel;   // The level of the author.
float PayOut;       // The final payout.
float averagePayout = 0.0;
float highestPayout = 0.0;

} //end main()
//==================================================================
// This part collects the inputs.
void userInput(int& Length, char& AuthorLevel )
{
cout << "Please enter the word count of the story (-1 to stop): ";
cin >> Length;
cout << "Now enter the author's level (A, B, or C): ";
cout << "Level: ";
cin >> AuthorLevel;
cout << endl;

};
//==================================================================
int computePay(int& Length, char& AuthorLevel)
{
    float PayOut;       // The final payout.
    int numA = 0;
    int numB = 0;
    int numC = 0;
    float averagePayout = 0.0;
    float highestPayout = 0.0;
    int counter = 0; // The number of times the program has ran.

    if(Length < 7500)
        {
            PayOut = 0.08 * Length;
        }
    else if(Length < 8000)
        {
            PayOut = 600;
        }
    else if(Length < 17500)
        {
            PayOut = 0.075 * Length;
        }
    else if(Length < 19000)
        {
            PayOut = 1313;
        }
    else
        {
            PayOut = 0.07 * Length;
        };
    if ((AuthorLevel == 'A') || (AuthorLevel == 'a'))
    {
        PayOut = 1.75 * PayOut;
    }
    else if(AuthorLevel == 'B' || AuthorLevel == 'b')
    {
        PayOut = 1.25 * PayOut;
    }
    else if (AuthorLevel == 'C' || AuthorLevel == 'c')
    {
        PayOut = 1.00 * PayOut;
    };
    do
    {
        userInput(Length, AuthorLevel);
        computePay(Length, AuthorLevel);
        counter++;
        cout << "The amount the author will make from the story will be: $"     << PayOut;
        cout << endl << endl;
          averagePayout = (averagePayout + PayOut) /2;
          if(highestPayout < PayOut)
            {
            highestPayout = PayOut;
             }
    }
    while(Length != -1);
};


//list the number of a b c 's
// for this use if statements to check  which was entered and then increment      that counter,
// system out the loop counter
//system out average payout and highest
//===================================================
```

This keeps having zero output and not running through computations or asking for inputs, and I honestly have no idea what I'm doing wrong. For the assignment, I also have to list the amount of A's, B's, and C's that are inputted, keep track of how many times it's looped, calculate an average payout after each and every loop, and also denote the largest payout after each loop, and I'm not so keen on how to do any of it. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

Your `main()` does not call any of the functions you have defined. It only consists of variable definitions.

Since this is C++, if your `main()` does not return explicitly, it will return a 0, which is what you see.

I am also not sure about your `int computePay()`: it doesn't seem to return any `int`, even though it should, probably? Or do you want it to be `void`?

Comment: How do I make main call a function or return? And I don't know what exactly I want from int computepay(), I just want it to work.

Comment: @DPuskas96 The first question is certainly answered within the first 10 pages of any textbook. The second question.... What does it mean, "just want it to work"? You realize that _you_ need to tell the compiler _what to do_ so that your program works _the way you want_, right?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your code:

1.) You're never calling any of your functions in `main()`. So all it does is creating some variables and end the program.
Try to add to main something like:

```
userInput(Length, AuthorLevel);
```

or

```
computePay(Length, AuthorLevel);
```

2.) Your functions `int computePay(int& Length, char& AuthorLevel)` & `int main()` are declared as returning int, but you never return anything: This causes undefined behavior.
Just add `return 0;` at the end of the function - or change the type to float and return your `PayOut` variable.

3.) You missed the prototype for `int computePay(int& Length, char& AuthorLevel);` at the beginning, so you won't be able to call it from your main function.

4.) Your comutePay function will never return and cause a stack overflow - everytime in your loop you make a recursive call, which will never end.
you need to check the `Length` variable before your `comutePay` call